# How do I get the Matlab data point labels correct? Part 2

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've created some Matlab code which anyone helping can run and see the problem.

When I run the following code, for each data point on my plot I seem to get all 15 labels instead of only 1 specific label.

So how do I get the Matlab data point labels correct for the following code?

Based on the the suggestions [from my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109468/how-do-i-get-the-matlab-data-point-labels-correct), I did the following:

I replaced these two lines of code:

```
labels = num2str(test_vector_label,'F%d');
labels_cell = cellstr(labels);
```

With this line of code as suggested:

```
labels_cell = strread(num2str(test_vector_label),'%s');
```

Now there are two follow-up questions:

1) A warning appears stating that I should use `textscan` instead of `strread`:

```
labels_cell = textscan(num2str(test_vector_label),'%s');
```

Then when I use `textscan` as in the above line of code above, I get an error?

> "Error using text Cell array of strings may only contain string and
>   numeric matrices"
>
> "Error in Code_Test (line 46)
>   text(x_val,y_val,labels_cell,'horizontal','left',
>   'vertical','bottom')"

2) How do I put a letter in front of the number labels? For example, in the original code I had put letter F followed by a number?

```
%--------------Randomly select training and testing data.-----------
num_data = 35;

data_idx = 1:35;

train_data_idx_tmp = randsample(num_data,20)

train_dataRand_idx = sort(train_data_idx_tmp)

% Lia = ismember(A,B) returns an array the same size as A, containing 1 (true) 
% where the elements of A are found in B, and 0 (false) elsewhere.
test_data_idx_tmp = ismember(data_idx,train_dataRand_idx)

test_dataRand_idx = data_idx(~test_data_idx_tmp)'

% Check to see if training and test data index are exclusive. 
check_train_test_idx = ismember(train_dataRand_idx,test_dataRand_idx)

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Testing stage.
test_vector = test_dataRand_idx; %Select randomly obtained testing data.

% Training stage.
train_vector = train_dataRand_idx; %Select randomly obtained training


x_val = [1:15];

y_val = 2*[1:15];

plot(x_val,y_val,'or','MarkerFaceColor','r')
grid on


%Put specific data point labels on plots.
test_vector_label = test_vector';
labels = num2str(test_vector_label,'F%d');   
labels_cell = cellstr(labels);
text(x_val,y_val,labels_cell,'horizontal','left', 'vertical','bottom')
```

Comment: Somehow your `labels_cell` do not contain strings. What do they contain?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation on [**strread**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strread.html) or [**textscan**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to see the difference in output?

Comment: Hi Ander, labels_cell is 1x1 cell containing a 15x1 cell array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**textscan**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) returns a cell array and not an array of strings. Try the following

```
labels_cell = textscan(num2str(test_vector_label),'%s');
labels_cell = strcat('F',labels_cell{1});
```

Comment: Hi  dpmcmlxxvi, I read the documentation of strread and textscan. I also implemented your suggestion above and it seems to work. Could you please help me understand how the above two lines of codes work? Your help will really deepen my understanding. Also, could you please explain how labels_cell{1} works when it contains 15 numbers with a preceding character F?

Comment: Put a break point at that line of the code and inspect the variable. You'll see why that works.